# Add a new convex hull layer on top of an LDA grpah - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I added some artificial data to the iris dataset (location) and did an LDA graph. How can I plot on the LDA plot another layer which will be the convex hull of the locationData.

Thanks.

Code:

```
myDF <- iris
locationData <- "UK"
myDF <- cbind(myDF, locationData)
myDF[30:45,6]<- "France"
myDF[105:145,6]<- "Japan"
myDF[146:150,6]<- "France"
Species<-myDF$Species

data4LDA<-lda(Species~. ,myDF[1:4] ) #Perfrom LDA 
LD1<-predict(data4LDA)$x[,1]
LD2<-predict(data4LDA)$x[,2]

dt<-data.table(Species,LD1,LD2)
dt[order(dt$Species),]

LDAplot <- ggplot(dt,aes(x=LD1,y=LD2)) +  
  geom_point(size = 2, aes(color=Species)) +
  stat_chull(aes(color = Species, fill = Species), geom = "polygon", alpha = 0.1) 
LDAplot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include location at a column in your `dt` object, and add another `stat_chull` mapped to it:

```r
dt <- data.table::data.table(Species, location = myDF$locationData, LD1,LD2)
dt[order(dt$Species),]

ggplot(dt,aes(LD1, LD2)) +  
  geom_point(size = 2, aes(color = Species)) +
  ggpubr::stat_chull(aes(color = Species, fill = after_scale(alpha(color, 0.1))), 
                     geom = "polygon", 
                     alpha = 0.1) +
  ggpubr::stat_chull(aes(fill = location, color = after_scale(alpha(fill, 1))), 
                     geom = "polygon", alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_brewer("Location", palette = "Set2") +
  scale_color_brewer("Species", palette = "Set1")
```

[image]